# How can I enumerate available voices and languages using espeak API?

Tags: c++, text-to-speech, espeak

I am using [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) *API* from *C++* to do some simple text to speech synthesis from my embedded app. Currently, I have copied this line from the basic example on how to get started:

```
espeak_SetVoiceByName("default");
```

This seems to work fine, however I know that espeak comes with several voices in several different languages. How can I **enumerate** those and later **select** them using espeak API?

Comment: Simply read the API doc?

Comment: I did not find the api doc. I actually did try, beleive it or not.

Comment: 1. Google `espeak`. 2. First result. 3. "Documents". 4. "espeak Library API". 5. Read. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for espeak API is the headerfile itself. You can find it [here](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/speak_lib.h).

To enumerate existing voices, you can use something like this:

```
const espeak_VOICE **list=espeak_ListVoices(0);
espeak_VOICE *voice=0;
for(;*list!=0;++list){
    voice=*list;
    if(0!=voice){
        //Look at voice parameters such has voice->name here
    }
}
```

Later when you have found a voice you want to use, you can set it with this:

```
if(0!=voice){
    espeak_SetVoiceByProperties(voice);
}
```

The `espeak_VOICE` struct is defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    const char *name;      // a given name for this voice. UTF8 string.
    const char *languages;       // list of pairs of (byte) priority + (string) language (and dialect qualifier)
    const char *identifier;      // the filename for this voice within espeak-data/voices
    unsigned char gender;  // 0=none 1=male, 2=female,
    unsigned char age;     // 0=not specified, or age in years
    unsigned char variant; // only used when passed as a parameter to espeak_SetVoiceByProperties
    unsigned char xx1;     // for internal use
    int score;       // for internal use
    void *spare;     // for internal use
} espeak_VOICE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `espeak_SetVoiceByProperties` function that's defined directly below the one you used.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
ESPEAK_API espeak_ERROR espeak_SetVoiceByName(const char *name);
/* Searches for a voice with a matching "name" field.  Language is not considered.
   "name" is a UTF8 string.

   Return: EE_OK: operation achieved
           EE_BUFFER_FULL: the command can not be buffered;
             you may try after a while to call the function again.
       EE_INTERNAL_ERROR.
*/

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
ESPEAK_API espeak_ERROR espeak_SetVoiceByProperties(espeak_VOICE *voice_spec);
/* An espeak_VOICE structure is used to pass criteria to select a voice.  Any of the following
   fields may be set:

   name     NULL, or a voice name

   languages  NULL, or a single language string (with optional dialect), eg. "en-uk", or "en"

   gender   0=not specified, 1=male, 2=female

   age      0=not specified, or an age in years

   variant  After a list of candidates is produced, scored and sorted, "variant" is used to index
            that list and choose a voice.
            variant=0 takes the top voice (i.e. best match). variant=1 takes the next voice, etc
*/
```

The `espeak_VOICE` structure is defined and documented not far above it.

The `espeak_ListVoices` function, to enumerate voices as requested, is defined right above the functions I quoted.

Comment: That is not the doc, that is the header. But thanks :-)

Comment: @LennartRolland: The header _is_ the doc. Do you not see the documenting comments in there that explain how to use it? I quoted the relevant ones in my answer ^

Comment: Also it does not answer the question.

Comment: @LennartRolland: Yes, it does. Read again.

Comment: Q was how to enumerate available voices.

Comment: @LennartRolland: Are you trolling or something? -.-

Comment: @LennartRolland: This is not a "read and quote the simple documentation for me" website.

Comment: Well Its not an accept the wrong answer kind of site either. Sorry If you find me to be annoying.